# MKMapView MapViewDelegate not called when annotation added

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I have the following UIViewController implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.MapKit;
using MonoTouch.CoreLocation;

namespace App.UI
{

    public partial class ProductsMapScreen : UIViewController
    {
        private MapDelegate mapDelegate;

        public ProductsMapScreen() : base("ProductsMapScreen", null)
        {
            TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem 
            { 
                Title = "Map", 
                Image = UIImage.FromFile("Images/tabmap.png")
            };
        }

        public Func<CLLocationCoordinate2D> GetCurrentLocation;

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            this.mapDelegate = new MapDelegate();
            this.mapView.Delegate = this.mapDelegate;

            SetVisibleRegion();
            AnnotateUsersCurrentLocation();

        }

        public override void ViewDidUnload()
        {
            base.ViewDidUnload();
            ReleaseDesignerOutlets();
        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            return (toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown);
        }

        private void AnnotateUsersCurrentLocation()
        {
            var location = GetCurrentLocation();
            this.mapView.AddAnnotation(new UserAnnotation(location));
        }

        private void SetVisibleRegion()
        {
            this.mapView.SetRegion(GetVisibleRegion(), true);
        }   

        private MKCoordinateRegion GetVisibleRegion()
        {
            var currentLocation = GetCurrentLocation();
            var span = new MKCoordinateSpan(0.2,0.2);
            var region = new MKCoordinateRegion(currentLocation,span);

            return region;
        }

        public class MapDelegate : MKMapViewDelegate 
        {
            public override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, NSObject annotation)
            {
                var userAnnotation = annotation as UserAnnotation;
                if(userAnnotation != null)
                    return getViewForUserAnnotation(mapView, userAnnotation);

                throw new Exception();
            }

            private MKAnnotationView getViewForUserAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, UserAnnotation annotation)
            {
                var annotationId = "userAnnotation";
                var annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation (annotationId) as MKPinAnnotationView;
                if (annotationView == null)
                    annotationView = new MKPinAnnotationView (annotation, annotationId);

                annotationView.PinColor = MKPinAnnotationColor.Green;
                annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;
                annotationView.Draggable = true;
                //annotationView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);

                return annotationView;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The MapViewDelegate never gets called to resolve the view for the single annotation I am adding. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I am not sure why the MapDelegate class would not work, but this implementation works for me. I am using MT 5.2.2.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.MapKit;
using MonoTouch.CoreLocation;

namespace App.UI
{

    public partial class ProductsMapScreen : UIViewController
    {
        public Func<CLLocationCoordinate2D> GetCurrentLocation;

        public ProductsMapScreen() : base("ProductsMapScreen", null)
        {
            TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem 
            { 
                Title = "Map", 
                Image = UIImage.FromFile("Images/tabmap.png")
            };
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            this.mapView.GetViewForAnnotation += GetViewForAnnotation;
            SetVisibleRegion();
            AnnotateUsersCurrentLocation();
        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            return (toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown);
        }

        private void AnnotateUsersCurrentLocation()
        {
            var location = GetCurrentLocation();
            this.mapView.AddAnnotation(new[] {new UserAnnotation(location)});
        }

        private void SetVisibleRegion()
        {
            this.mapView.SetRegion(GetVisibleRegion(), true);
        }   

        private MKCoordinateRegion GetVisibleRegion()
        {
            var currentLocation = GetCurrentLocation();
            var span = new MKCoordinateSpan(0.2,0.2);
            var region = new MKCoordinateRegion(currentLocation,span);

            return region;
        }

        private MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, NSObject annotation)
        {
            var userAnnotation = annotation as UserAnnotation;
            if(userAnnotation != null)
                return getViewForUserAnnotation(mapView, userAnnotation);

            throw new Exception();
        }

        private MKAnnotationView getViewForUserAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, UserAnnotation annotation)
        {
            var annotationId = "userAnnotation";
            var annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation (annotationId) as MKPinAnnotationView;
            if (annotationView == null)
                annotationView = new MKPinAnnotationView (annotation, annotationId);

            annotationView.PinColor = MKPinAnnotationColor.Green;
            annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;
            annotationView.Draggable = true;
            annotationView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);

            return annotationView;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem - in my case I was confusing Coordinates (lat/long points on a globe) and MKMapPoints (2d xy points on a map).  I'm not sure if that's the same problem you're having, but it's the first thing I'd check.  The delegate won't get called if it doesn't think it's in the visible region of the map

you can convert between them with MKMapPointForCoordinate & MKCoordinateForMapPoint

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html